# Get lower diagonal indices from a square matrix sorted by column

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a pairwise plot in the lower diagonal of a [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html). Hence, I need the indices from the lower diagonal of a square matrix. Due to the order of my plot, I need them to be sorted by column. For example, suppose that I have the following matrix 4x4:

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4]
[ 5,  6,  8,  7]
[ 8,  9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
```

I need their indices in the following order: 5, 8, 12, 9, 13, 14. How can I accomplish that in a few lines of code? I will share my solution, but I feel I could accomplish that in a more elegant way.

#### My Solution

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n = 4 # Matrix order
>>> a = np.arange(1,n*n+1).reshape(n,n)
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> index = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
>>> a.T[index]
array([ 5,  9, 13, 10, 14, 15])
```

#### Context

What I would do next, is something like:

```
>>> subplot_idx = a.T[index]
>>> for idx in subplot_idx:
...     plt.subplot(n, n, idx)
...     # plot something
```

Comment: Just clarifying - indexes start  at 0, so you want to get the desired index-1 (4, 7, 11, 8, 12, 13) right?

Comment: That seems elegant enough to me already

Comment: Are you grabbing the indices or the elements themselves?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder, I know it is weird, but the indexes of [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) start with one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cheaper way would be to avoid the indices creation part and use a mask for [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). Now, since its row-major ordering in NumPy and we need lower diag elements, we would need to use a upper diag mask (mask with upper diag elements set as True, while rest are False) on a transposed version of the input array. We would be using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to efficiently create a upper diag mask with a `ranged array outer comparison` and index into transposed array. Thus, for an input array `a` it would be -

```
r = np.arange(len(a))
out = a.T[r[:,None] < r]
```

Assuming that we would be working with matrices that are smaller than `65536 x 65536` sized array, we could use a lower precision for `r` and thus achieve noticeable performance boost -

```
r = np.arange(len(a), dtype=np.uint16)
```

Same idea and using the NumPy builtin [`np.tri`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html) to create a lower diag mask and thus have an *`elegant`* one-liner way (as asked) would be -

```
a.T[~np.tri(len(a), dtype=bool)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [116]: a
Out[116]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [117]: a.T[~np.tri(len(a), dtype=bool)]
Out[117]: array([ 5,  9, 13, 10, 14, 15])
```

#### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
# Original soln
def extract_lower_diag_org(a):
    n = len(a)
    index = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
    return a.T[index]

# Proposed soln
def extract_lower_diag_mask(a):
    r = np.arange(len(a), dtype=np.uint16)
    return a.T[r[:,None] < r]
```

Timings on a bigger array -

```
In [142]: a = np.random.rand(5000,5000)

In [143]: %timeit extract_lower_diag_org(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 216 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit extract_lower_diag_mask(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.2 ms per loop

In [145]: %timeit a.T[~np.tri(len(a), dtype=bool)]
10 loops, best of 3: 52.1 ms per loop
```

Seeing a **`4x+`** speedup for these large arrays with the proposed mask-based methods.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
n = 4
1 + np.ravel_multi_index(np.triu_indices(n, 1)[::-1], (n, n))
# array([ 5,  9, 13, 10, 14, 15])
```

Similar to your solution, but doesn't require setting up the full square array.